# Fail to send data back to React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am new to React and Node js. I have defined a function that run a Python script from my Node.js application using child process, and I have an router post that called pythonExecute and return that result back to
React. Router seemed to have trouble sending the data back to react using `react.json(data)`,can someone please help and see what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Function

```
const pythonExecute = (data, input) => {
    const res = {
      err: false,
      msg: ""
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        const fileName = "test.py"
        saveFile(fileName, data)
          .then(()=>{
              const filePath = path.join(__dirname,"../test.py")
              const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
              const pythonProcess = spawn('python',[filePath]);   
              pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
                console.log(data.toString());
                resolve(data)
            });
          })
          .catch(()=>{
            console.log("ERROR SAVE FILE"+ saveFileRes)
            const err = {
              err: true,
              output: "Internal Server Error!"
            }
            resolve(err)
          })
    })
```

Express Router

```
const execute = require('../../compile/compile')
router.post('/submit', (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    const code = req.body.code
    const input = req.body.input
    const lang = req.body.lang
    return execute.pythonExecute(code, input)
    .then(data=>{
    console.log("SUCCESSFULL PROMISE " + data)
    console.log("SENDING " + data)
    res.write(data)
    deleteFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../test.py'))
    })
    .catch(err => {
    console.log("ERROR PROMISE " + err)
    deleteFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../test.py'))
})
    }  
)
```

React

```
export default class Ide extends Component {
    state={
        code: code.cpp,
        result: 'Submit Code to See Result',
        lang: 'cpp'
    }

    onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        alert("submit code")
        axios.post(`${secret.url}code/submit`,this.state)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res.data)
                const data = res.data
                if(data.err){
                    // Error in user code
                    this.setState({
                        result: data.error
                    })
                }else{
                    this.setState({
                        result: data.output
                    })
                }

            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
    }
```

Logs

```
Server started at port 8000
{
  code: '# Your code will come here\nprint("b")',
  result: 'Submit Code to See Result',
  lang: 'python'
}
SAVING FILES
The file was saved!
FILE PATH >> \ide-server\test.py
[6 7 8]

SUCCESSFULL PROMISE [6 7 8]

SENDING [6 7 8]

File deleted!
SORRY NOT DELETED
File deleted!
File deleted!
```

Comment: do console.log(res.data) output {
  code: '# Your code will come here\nprint("b")',
  result: 'Submit Code to See Result',
  lang: 'python'
}?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send a `JSON` structure to react App try to do on server:

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(data))
```

*data must be like {values: [6, 7, 8]} or smth else*

on client:

```
axios.post(`${secret.url}code/submit`,this.state)
  .then(res=> res.json())               
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  ...
```

if you want to send a `plain text`:

```
res.send(data)
```

on client:

```
axios.post(`${secret.url}code/submit`,this.state)
  .then(res=> res.text())               
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  ...
```

And don't forget use `res.end()` after `res.write()`;